# Why won't express.js authenticate?

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, express

I'm developing a `node.js` server application, which is running on `localhost:8080`. I'm doing a login request in 2 ways, only one of which is working. I'm guessing the problem is with the `req` object.

1) I'm sending the request via Postman Chrome extension.

That way everything **works fine**. I'm authenticated and redirected to the home page.

2) I do it manually using `curl` and it fails to authenticate the user (`req.isAuthenticated()` returns `false` and I cannot access any routes requiring `user` permissions. The exact command I use is:

```
 curl -X POST --header "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d "email=some.email%40gmail.com&password=somePass" "http://localhost:8080/login"
```

Here is the `diff` of my `req` objects:

```
30c30
<       { fd: 17,
---
>       { fd: 18,
90c90
<      bytesRead: 645,
---
>      bytesRead: 466,
98c98
<         _connections: 1,
---
>         _connections: 2,
108,110c108,136
<      _idleNext: { _idleNext: [Circular], _idlePrev: [Circular] },
<      _idlePrev: { _idleNext: [Circular], _idlePrev: [Circular] },
<      _idleStart: 1446646833256,
---
>      _idleNext: 
>       { _connecting: false,
>         _handle: [Object],
>         _readableState: [Object],
>         readable: true,
>         domain: null,
>         _events: [Object],
>         _maxListeners: 10,
>         _writableState: [Object],
>         writable: true,
>         allowHalfOpen: true,
>         onend: [Function],
>         destroyed: false,
>         errorEmitted: false,
>         bytesRead: 1112,
>         _bytesDispatched: 1772,
>         _pendingData: null,
>         _pendingEncoding: '',
>         server: [Object],
>         _idleTimeout: 120000,
>         _idleNext: [Object],
>         _idlePrev: [Circular],
>         _idleStart: 1446646833575,
>         parser: [Object],
>         ondata: [Function],
>         _paused: false,
>         _httpMessage: null },
>      _idlePrev: { _idleNext: [Circular], _idlePrev: [Object] },
>      _idleStart: 1446646871908,
153c179
<       { fd: 17,
---
>       { fd: 18,
213c239
<      bytesRead: 645,
---
>      bytesRead: 466,
221c247
<         _connections: 1,
---
>         _connections: 2,
231,233c257,285
<      _idleNext: { _idleNext: [Circular], _idlePrev: [Circular] },
<      _idlePrev: { _idleNext: [Circular], _idlePrev: [Circular] },
<      _idleStart: 1446646833256,
---
>      _idleNext: 
>       { _connecting: false,
>         _handle: [Object],
>         _readableState: [Object],
>         readable: true,
>         domain: null,
>         _events: [Object],
>         _maxListeners: 10,
>         _writableState: [Object],
>         writable: true,
>         allowHalfOpen: true,
>         onend: [Function],
>         destroyed: false,
>         errorEmitted: false,
>         bytesRead: 1112,
>         _bytesDispatched: 1772,
>         _pendingData: null,
>         _pendingEncoding: '',
>         server: [Object],
>         _idleTimeout: 120000,
>         _idleNext: [Object],
>         _idlePrev: [Circular],
>         _idleStart: 1446646833575,
>         parser: [Object],
>         ondata: [Function],
>         _paused: false,
>         _httpMessage: null },
>      _idlePrev: { _idleNext: [Circular], _idlePrev: [Object] },
>      _idleStart: 1446646871908,
279,281c331
<      'cache-control': 'no-cache',
<      origin: 'chrome-extension://fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop',
<      'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
---
>      origin: 'http://localhost:8081',
283c333
<      'postman-token': '18ad28a2-c866-0b01-3790-42e7f88be021',
---
>      'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
284a335
>      referer: 'http://localhost:8081/',
286,287c337
<      'accept-language': 'pl-PL,pl;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4',
<      cookie: 'connect.sid=s%3AP2RZKo9-hOSz1N29dFS5SUH_XGMHSxOu.SgxDDkHPhKwz2wbD4SS%2FGQAHV6QiBXAJrpezNedo6FA' },
---
>      'accept-language': 'pl-PL,pl;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4' },
297c347
<       { fd: 17,
---
>       { fd: 18,
357c407
<      bytesRead: 645,
---
>      bytesRead: 466,
365c415
<         _connections: 1,
---
>         _connections: 2,
375,377c425,453
<      _idleNext: { _idleNext: [Circular], _idlePrev: [Circular] },
<      _idlePrev: { _idleNext: [Circular], _idlePrev: [Circular] },
<      _idleStart: 1446646833256,
---
>      _idleNext: 
>       { _connecting: false,
>         _handle: [Object],
>         _readableState: [Object],
>         readable: true,
>         domain: null,
>         _events: [Object],
>         _maxListeners: 10,
>         _writableState: [Object],
>         writable: true,
>         allowHalfOpen: true,
>         onend: [Function],
>         destroyed: false,
>         errorEmitted: false,
>         bytesRead: 1112,
>         _bytesDispatched: 1772,
>         _pendingData: null,
>         _pendingEncoding: '',
>         server: [Object],
>         _idleTimeout: 120000,
>         _idleNext: [Object],
>         _idlePrev: [Circular],
>         _idleStart: 1446646833575,
>         parser: [Object],
>         ondata: [Function],
>         _paused: false,
>         _httpMessage: null },
>      _idlePrev: { _idleNext: [Circular], _idlePrev: [Object] },
>      _idleStart: 1446646871908,
473c549
<         bytesRead: 645,
---
>         bytesRead: 466,
481c557
<         _idleStart: 1446646833256,
---
>         _idleStart: 1446646871908,
500c576
<         bytesRead: 645,
---
>         bytesRead: 466,
508c584
<         _idleStart: 1446646833256,
---
>         _idleStart: 1446646871908,
515c591
<         'access-control-allow-origin': 'chrome-extension://fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop',
---
>         'access-control-allow-origin': 'http://localhost:8081',
535c611
<   cookies: { 'connect.sid': 's:P2RZKo9-hOSz1N29dFS5SUH_XGMHSxOu.SgxDDkHPhKwz2wbD4SS/GQAHV6QiBXAJrpezNedo6FA' },
---
>   cookies: {},
552c628
<    { sessions: {},
---
>    { sessions: { 'T2mMlB997N-CA371f0kp1kHMiEzc_wTE': '{"cookie":{"originalMaxAge":null,"expires":null,"httpOnly":true,"path":"/"},"passport":{"user":{"id":"55dde27a0f6ff71b72dc7981","active":true,"employment":[{"employee":{"_id":"5605250fcac9a42f0e4124bd","createdAt":"2015-09-13T10:11:12.345Z","schoolId":"55d1e957daea17d3e90a3c50","userId":"55dde27a0f6ff71b72dc7981","timesOff":[{"timeFrom":"2015-11-11T16:11:32.714Z","timeTo":"2015-11-27T16:11:32.714Z","_id":"5630f1350c2efb2e54206aaa"}],"specialties":[],"permissions":["manager"]},"school":{"_id":"55d1e957daea17d3e90a3c50","address":{"zipcode":35665,"streetNum":11,"street":"Main Str.","country":"Italy","city":"Milano"},"contacts":{"phone":"123-456-789"},"email":"email@example.com","logo":"someURL","name":"Another sample ski & snowboard school","resortId":"55ddd14348c851b305cfa2a6","active":true,"openingHours":["7-14","4-21","7-18","2-22","N/A","N/A","N/A"],"defaultMeetingPoints":[{"name":"Black horse pass","geo":{"lat":46.462209,"lng":10.372391}}]}}],"roles":["user"]}}}' },
555c631
<   sessionID: 'T2mMlB997N-CA371f0kp1kHMiEzc_wTE',
---
>   sessionID: 'u4Z31P-B6qsPneDfj_6vIgd8hg0UdX-g',
```

(the working one as the 1st - top file).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I had to guess it would be because [cookies need to be enabled](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/http-cookies.html) on your cURL request.

Try adding the `--cookie` option to your curl request and see if that helps at all?

Command would look similar to this:

```
curl -X POST --cookie ./cookie.txt --header "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d "email=some.email%40gmail.com&password=somePass" "http://localhost:8080/login"
```

Comment: Where do I add this option? It requires a parameter, right?

Comment: Updated: Try passing the cookie parameter a file name (updated command above)